# XNA game Development, update sprite

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard, state

would someone tell what i did wrong in this code...i am trying to move a sprite whenever the left arrow on the keyboard is pressed. but when i run the code the game window open and shut off prtty quickly

```cs
public class Sprite
{
    private Texture2D texture;
    private Vector2 position;

    public Sprite(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.texture = texture;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }

    void Update(KeyboardState keyboardstate, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (keyboardstate.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            Velocity = new Vector2(-1, 0);
            position+= ((Velocity) *(float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }

   public Vector2 Velocity { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Did you modify code in Program.cs? I can't see any reason that your window would close immediately in the code you've posted. Does the window stay open if you just run the default new Xna game project?

Comment: I'm looking at your code as well, what Aranda is saying is correct.

This code should compile and run normally, and should not effect your window opening or closing randomly.

Check both your Program.cs as well as your main Game Loop code generated by the project when it was created.

Compare it with a default XNA game project.